# Reading multiple files in a folder using JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, filereader

I'm trying to read in the text documents located in a folder(inside eclipse package src/myFolder) into a String[]. How can I achieve this? Should I use a bufferedReader or a Scanner? Each word in the document must be tagged to a document ID. Eg: If the first document has the sentence "Spring is here" and the second text document has the sentence "Let's have fun". The output will be like

```
Spring     1
is         1
here       1
Let's      2
have       2
fun        2
```

My main concern is reading multiple documents. Here is my attempt of reading the files.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] docs = {"Spring is here"};

    File[] listOfMyFiles=null;
    String[] myDocs;

    File folder = new File("src/Lab1_Data");
      listOfMyFiles = folder.listFiles();
      myDocs = new String[listOfMyFiles.length];
      for(int i=0;i<listOfMyFiles.length;i++) {
         myDocs[i] = listOfMyFiles[i].getName();
         System.out.println("File: " + listOfMyFiles[i].getName());
      }
    ....
```

I get the Null Pointer exception, what might be the error, is it the path?

Comment: Use `URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/Lab1_Data"); File file = new File(uri.toURI());`

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be something like this:

```
public File getFolder(String folderName) throws URISyntaxException {
       URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/Lab1_Data");
       File file = new File(url.toURI());
       return file;
}
```

You are getting NullPointerException because the code did not found folder location and due to this your file object is having null value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you made a mistake copying your code but you declare an array of Files called `listOfFiles`, but later you try to assign to a variable named `listOfMyFiles`. What I don't get is why JAVA isn't telling you that you used an undeclared variable.

By the way can you copy the whole Exception Stack or the line where is raised?

Comment: Made the change, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Changing `File[] listOfFiles=null;` to `File[] listOfMyFiles=null;` seems to fix it.

You might be getting a `NullPointerException` if the directory you're referencing doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The File class operates on a path of the operating system. Calling

```
new File( "src/myFolder")
```

constructs a logical path object relative to the current working directory. And this is dependant where you have started your program. It has nothing to do with the classpath.

If you want access files within the classpath you have to use the Classloader.getSystemResource method:

```
        URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource( "src/Lab1_Data");
        File ch = new File(url.toURI());
        File[] files = ch.listFiles();
```

Assuming "src" is the root elemet of your package path. Afterwards you can iterate on the files:

```
        for ( File file : files )
        {
            // do something with the file
        }
```